# What is malloc: recording malloc (but not VM allocation) stacks using lite mode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode8

Hello what is this follwoing message in xcode debug.

SomeApp(2389,0x1092763c0) malloc: recording malloc (but not VM allocation) stacks using lite mode

xCode 8.3

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The log message seems to come from

> libmalloc-53.1.1/src/malloc.c

as the source code is available [here](https://opensource.apple.com/source/libmalloc/libmalloc-53.1.1/src/malloc.c)
at line #567 - or at least search in text "recording malloc (but not VM".

```
malloc_printf(ASL_LEVEL_INFO, "recording malloc (but not VM allocation) stacks to disk using standard recorder\n");
```

About the logging environment, you should have a look on the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/ManagingMemory/Articles/MallocDebug.html).

If you are worried about the log message, I'd refer to the inline comments in source:

```
// Set up stack logging as early as possible to catch all ensuing VM allocations,
// including those from _malloc_printf and malloc zone setup.  Make sure to set
// __syscall_logger after this, because prepare_to_log_stacks() itself makes VM
// allocations that we aren't prepared to log yet.
```

So I guess you should ignore it unless you want to debug memory allocations.

In order to set/unset the malloc debug environment, select *Edit Scheme...* from the project toolbar and enter the *Diagnostics* panel.

[image: XCode Scheme Panel]

Comment: i haven't enabled any environment variables. how to disable this log?

Comment: In your XCode project toolbar, enter *Edit Scheme...* from the dropdown menu, select the *Diagnostics* panel and check the Memory Management options.